# Prove column space of product of matrices is a subset

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A, B$ be matrices such that the product $AB$ exists. Is the column space of $AB$ a subset of the column space of $A$?

This is **true,** but how do I show it?

**Attempt:**

Let $m_1, ... , m_k$ be the columns of $B$, it follows that

$AB = \begin{bmatrix}
Am_1 & ... & Am_k 
\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies \text{col } (AB) = \text{span } \{Am_1, ... , Am_k \}$

But how do I show it is a subset of $\text{col } (A)$?

Comment: Not "subset" (there would be nothing to prove) but "subspace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column space of $AB$ is a subspace of the column space of $A$. Indeed, the column space of $AB$ is the span of $\{Am_1,Am_2,\dots,Am_k\}$ and $Am_i$ belongs to the column space of $A$.

Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$ and $x$ an $n\times 1$ column. If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are the columns of $A$ and
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
then
$$
Ax=x_1a_1+x_2a_2+\dots+x_na_n
$$
which belongs to the column space of $A$.

Also the converse is true: if you take a linear combination of the columns of $A$ you can easily build a suitable vector $x$.

---

Alternative view. Suppose $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times p$. Then we can consider the linear maps
$$
f_A\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m,\quad f_A(x)=Ax
\\
f_B\colon\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^n,\quad f_B(y)=By
$$
and similarly
$$
f_{AB}\colon\mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^m,\quad f_{AB}(y)=ABy
$$
Then
$$
f_{AB}=f_A\circ f_B
$$
so the range of $f_{AB}$ is a subspace of the range of $f_A$.

The argument above shows the column space of $A$ is the range of $f_A$ (and similarly for the other maps).

Comment: Hello! I've edited a little, can you help me take off from where Is stopped in showing its a subset of the column space of $A$?

Comment: How can we say $Am_i$ belongs in the column space of $A$ though?

Comment: Because of the definition of multiplication of a matrix by a vector. $Ax = \sum x_ia_i$, where $a_i$ are the columns of $A$.

Comment: @Amad27 The column space of the $m\times n$ matrix $A$ consists precisely of the columns of the form $Ax$, where $x$ is any $n\times 1$ column.

Comment: Thanks! Just a question. We would be required to show an element in the span of $\{Am_1, Am_2, ..., Am_k\}$ is in the column space of $A$ right? so don't we need to use a general constant and show that $\overrightarrow{x} = c_1Am_1 + c_2Am_2 + ... + c_kAm_k \in \text{col } A$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not hard to see this:
for $\forall\,y \in \, col(AB)$, there $\exists x$, such that $ABx=y$;
and there $\exists z=Bx$, such that $Az=A(Bx)=y$ $\Rightarrow \,y\in\,col(A)$.

From above we know that $\forall y,\,y \in col(AB)\Rightarrow\,y \in col(A)$, hence $col(AB) \subset col(A)$.